# Regex to find date in a string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can find the alpha representation of a month, along with the numerical year followed by it.

Examples:

- Today's month is June 2012
- This is a setence containing a date for may 2012 and that is all.
- December 2012
- June 2012 is the date of this year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific examples you can do it with an alternation for the names of the months, and `\d{4}` for the year:

```
/\b(?:January|February|March|...|December)\s+\d{4}\b/i
```

The `i` is for case-insensitive.

The `\b` are word boundaries.

I'm assuming that the years are any four digits, though you may of course want to extend (or restrict) this range, depending on the needs of your application.

Comment: Great, and im assuming just dropping '/i' to ignore case?

Comment: Check out http://kuxyz.blogspot.ro/ on how to restrict the numeric range to any range you would want

Comment: @Ωmega: I posted first, so how could I have copied you?  (For the record, I don't think you copied me - this is just the most obvious answer.)

Comment: @Atticus Drop 'i' and not '/i' if you want case sensitivity.

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you like to explain why you downvoted this?

Comment: @MarkByers I can think of one person... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
/\b(?:January|February|March|April|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d{4}\b/i
```